# Prob. on Technique Of Counting

Tags: probability

If 8 identical blackboards are to be divided among 4 schools,

i) how many divisions are possible?

ii) How many, if each school must receive at least 1 blackboard?

### -----------------------------------------------------------

in (i) I got to S(4,8) = C(11,8)

in (ii) I got to S(4,4) = C(7,4)

---

I found answer for (i) was C(8-1,4-1), but I don't know why..

Comment: I would have thought (i) was $C(8+4-1,4-1)$ and (ii) was $C(8-1,4-1)$ using stars and bars which is essentially what you have

Comment: Do you mean you should have thought in the same solution ?

Comment: This will be helpful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Why do you have two different answers for (i)?  The answer $C(11, 8)$ is correct for (i), as is the answer $C(7, 4)$ for (ii).

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is equivalent to finding $x_i\geq 0$, 
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=8
$$ 
Using stars and bars, there are 
$$
{8+4-1 \choose 3}={11 \choose 3}={11 \choose 8}
$$
Or the ways of arranging the 11 objects (3 walls corresponding to the 4 schools) and 8 blackboards.

For the second one, distribute the 4 boards to start with which you can do in ${4\choose 4}=1$, then use the above logic to find places for 3 walls in $4+4-1=7$ spots.